# ec2 instance "Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, rubygems, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having trouble with uploading and deploying ruby app on Elastic Beanstalk 
 In the '/var/log/eb-activity.log' there was an error '/opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler.rb:221:in `rescue in root': Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)'.

[image]

here is part of the code on line 221 from bundler.rb from the ec2 instance

```
  def root
  @root ||= begin
              default_gemfile.dirname.expand_path
            rescue GemfileNotFound
              bundle_dir = default_bundle_dir
              raise GemfileNotFound, "Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory" unless bundle_dir
              Pathname.new(File.expand_path("..", bundle_dir))
            end
   end
```

This website has full code of bundler.rb that is exact similar to my bundler.rb

http://sistework.mspbs.gov.py/redmin/GEM_HOME/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb

Here is an image of GemFile
[image]

by the way usually I run this command before i zip the app and upload it

```
bundle package
```

from this link 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/locally-packaging-gem-dependencies-for-ruby-applications-in-elastic-beanstalk/

Comment: You say... 'I suspect that this error occurred because a Gemfile was missing in the application bundle'... Does this mean that your app does not have a Gemfile?

Comment: @AlejandroMarti discard the sentence i was talking about the puma app but i update the question with an image from gemFile

Answer (score 1):

Two things usually solve this for me.

1. I didn't bundle install.
2. Sometimes, I have to run things with bundle exec

`bundle exec <Your path> puma`

Comment: I can run those command with no problem, usually i run bundle install then bundle package and then i zip the file and upload and deploy to Elastic Beanstalk. after that i will get the error in eb-activity.log that `rescue in root': Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)'.